# Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-e7AmlG/django-filter

Tags: python, django, pip, virtualenv

Im trying to run a pip install on a pip_requirements.txt ([readthedocs](https://read-the-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/install.html) local install) file in Cygwin within a virtualenv and am running into some issues.

Python version:Python 2.7.8

pip version: pip 6.0.8

virtualenv: 12.0.7

Here is the console [output](http://paste.debian.net/hidden/638389e9/).

Whats odd is that it cannot find the directory and never creates the temp directory. This install works fine on linux, I am just running into issues on the windows box. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following command:

```
python -m pip install --upgrade --force pip
```